# Conditional expectation and independence with respect to $\sigma$-algebra and null set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

This question concerns an extension of a previously solved question regarding measure-theoretic definitions of conditional expectation and conditional independence with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra and an event $A$ (see [Conditional expectation and independence on $\sigma$-algebras and events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853989/conditional-expectation-and-independence-on-sigma-algebras-and-events?rq=1)). The mentioned thread considers the situation when $A$ has positive probability. I am interested in the special case when $A$ is a null set.

**Background:**

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $X,Y$ be $\mathcal F$-measurable random variables. Let $\mathcal G$ be a sub-$\sigma$ algebra of $\mathcal F$. When $A \in \mathcal F$ and $P(A)>0$ we can make sense of conditional independence with respect to an event and $\sigma$-algebra under $P$ in the usual way. Indeed, by defining the probability measure $P_A(\cdot) := \frac{P(A \cap \cdot)}{P(A)}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ we make the identification
$$ X \perp_P Y | \mathcal G,A \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad X \perp_{P_A} Y | \mathcal G. $$
I.e. the statement on the left is *defined* to be the statement on the right. We understand in measure theoretic terms what the independence statement on the right means. Likewise, we understand in measure theoretic terms what e.g. $E_{P_A}[X | \mathcal G]$ means.

**My question:**

I am really interested in the general situation when $A\in \mathcal F$ is a $P$-null set, but to make the problem more concrete I assume in the following that $A =  \{Z=z \}$, where $Z$ is a continuous random variable. It then seems natural to make use of a Markov kernel $K$ (assuming that it exists) from $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ to $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ and define a regular conditional distribution given $Z=z$ as follows: $P_z(\cdot) := K(z,\cdot)$. I wonder if it is correct to make sense of conditional independence with respect to $\mathcal G$ and $Z=z$ as above:
$$ X \perp_P Y | \mathcal G,Z=z \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad X \perp_{P_z} Y | \mathcal G. $$
I.e. that conditional independence and expectation is defined in terms of $P_z$. Since $P_z$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ we can make sense of the conditional independence statement on the right. Likewise, for $X \in L^1(P_z)$ there is a unique $\mathcal G$-measurable variable $H$ such that $E_{P_z}[I_G H] = E_{P_z}[I_G X]$ for each $G \in \mathcal G$. I wonder if this is a way to make sense of $E_P[X | \mathcal G, Z=z]$.

The obvious limitation here, it seems to me, is that one can not generally assume that such a Markov kernel exists (unless one imposes some special structure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, e.g. that it is a Borel space, which seems undesirable). On the other hand, if the construction I'm thinking of is incorrect then I have no clue as to how objects like $E_P[X | \mathcal G, Z=z]$ are defined in general! Of course, if $\mathcal G = \sigma(L)$ for some random variable $L$, we are really talking about objects like $E_P[X | L, Z=z]$, which statisticians work with and manipulate all the time.

Comment: Assuming that you have a Borel space is undesirable?

Comment: @Andrew I meant that it is undesirable to assume that the underlying measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ is a Borel space. By Borel space I mean the following: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space. The thing is that if we have two measurable spaces and the second of them is a Borel space, then there is a Markov kernel from the first to the second by the classical disintegration theorem. In general my impression is that it is desirable to leave the underlying measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ as unspecified as possible.

Comment: Sure, but what applications do you have in mind where we don't have a Borel space?

Comment: @Andrew I don't have a specific application or example in mind. I guess it is just my inclination to let the underlying measurable space be unspecified. But I'm willing to put that inclination aside, at least for the moment. Suppose we are willing to assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ is a Borel space. Do you think the above way of making sense of conditional expectation is valid?

Comment: Take a random element $G$ such that $\sigma(G) = \mathcal{G}$. Given two functions $f$ and $g$, the conditional expectation $E[f(X)g(Y) \mid G, Z]$ is a function of $G$ and $Z$, say $\eta(G,Z)$. Then one defines $E[f(X)g(Y) \mid G, Z=z] = \eta(G, z)$. I think the key point to be shown is $E[f(X)g(Y) \mid G, Z=z] = E_{P_z}[f(X)g(Y) \mid G]$. Maybe one has to introduce a regular conditional probability given $(G=\gamma, Z=z)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Stephane, I think you have a point there! I will look more closely into it